# Filtering a Model's associated collections based on a User's CanCan abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Users belong to an organization. Users can view all organizations, but can only view users within their organization. When a user views the organization, I have to add filter logic to the view, so `@organizations.users` becomes `@organizations.users.select{|u| can?(:read, u)}`.

Is there a way to manage this more transparently or elegantly? Is there a way to get rid of `select{|u| can?(:read, u)}` or move it to a DRY place?

**Relevant code:**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class Ability
  ...
  can :read, User, :organization => @user.organization
end
```

organizations/show.html.erb: (current, sucky version)

```
<% if @organization.users.select{|u| can?(:read, u)}.any? %>
  <h4>Contacts</h4>
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <% for user in @organization.users.select{|u| can?(:read, u)} %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to user, user, class: "user" %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I want something closer to this view instead:

organizations/show.html.erb:

```
<% if @organization.users.any? %>
  <h4>Contacts</h4>
  <ul class="unstyled">
    <% for user in @organization.users %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to user, user, class: "user" %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

I'm avoiding `accessible_by` because I have an ability definition that uses a block.

```
class Ability
  ...
  can :read, User, :organization => @user.organization
  can :read, User do |user|
    user.is? :technical_contact
  end
end
```

I know that `accessible_by` can work with blocks, but only if a SQL fragment is provided. Since my users have many roles and are stored as a bitmask, I don't have a SQL fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CanCan has built in support for this with the `accessible_by` method that is available on your active record models.

See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records for more information.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I'm avoiding `accessible_by` because I have an ability definition that uses a block. I updated the question to clarify, but will accept your answer or at least vote it up if there is a better way for my scenario.